# C++: Displaying a saved char value to screen

Tags: c++

Whenever the below c++ program below is run, I keep getting the same output which is " A ", even if I enter a grade value of say, 84, or 76. I am confused as to why the output is always " A" and not the grade letter value it should be based off the number grade input. I know it is most likely a logical error in my code, but I cant seem to understand why.

```
char letterGrade;
int scoreGrade;

cout << "Enter Course Name: ";
cin >> courseName;

cout << "Score Grade Recieved: ";
cin >> scoreGrade;
while (scoreGrade < 0 || scoreGrade > 100) {
    cout << "Invalid Entry, Enter Score Grade: ";
    cin >> scoreGrade;
}

if (scoreGrade >= 90 || scoreGrade <= 100) {
    letterGrade = 'A';
}
else if (scoreGrade >= 80 || scoreGrade < 90) {
    letterGrade = 'B';
}
else if (scoreGrade >= 70 || scoreGrade < 80) {
    letterGrade = 'C';
}
else if (scoreGrade >= 60 || scoreGrade < 70) {
    letterGrade = 'D';
}
else
    letterGrade = 'F';

cout << letterGrade;
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Let me just try to explain what's the meaning of this condition: `scoreGrade >= 90 || scoreGrade <= 100`. This condition will be evaluated to true if either `scoreGrade >= 90` is true **or** `scoreGrade <= 100`. So, for example, it will be true if `scoreGrade` is 1000000 and i will be true if `scoreGrade` is -1000000000000. What you probably want is to give an `A` if it's between 90 and 100, but that's not the correct way of doing it. I will not tell you the correct way because I think this is a nice challenge for you to figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your conditions are being evaluated to true every time.

```
if (scoreGrade >= 90 || scoreGrade <= 100)
```

Evaluates to true no matter what value is entered. This is saying if the value is greater than or equal to 90 or the value is less than 100. You should use the && operator instead of || which would change the statement to greater than or equal to 90 and the value is less than 100

Comment: Thank you for explaining this to me, It helped me understand what was going on. changing my logical operators to && fixed it.

Comment: no problem. Please click the check if this answer was indeed a solution.